# Integrating git repositories created through gitlab on trac

Tags: git, gitlab, trac

I am trying to integrate a git repository, created through gitlab, on trac but I am encountering error

```
Trac[PyGIT] ERROR: GIT control files missing in <to gitlab repository>
```

Has anyone experienced this already? Please share your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue for non-bare repositories. You can either append `/.git` (`\.git` on Windows) to the path or upgrade to Trac >= 1.0.2.

The Git control files directory contains content like the following:

```
$ ls .git
branches     FETCH_HEAD  Git_nUN4JU  hooks  logs       packed-refs
config       Git_ech5ro  Git_VH8IIq  index  objects    refs
description  Git_hdrpql  HEAD        info   ORIG_HEAD  svn
```

You must use a path that points to this directory. In Trac >= 1.0.2 you can point to the parent of this directory for a non-bare repository, which is more intuitive for most users when the repository is not a bare repository because the `.git` directory is contained in the root of the Git repository.

Comment: Sorry it will not really work because I am integrating a bare git repository. I will try the upgrade and will update you. Thanks.

Comment: I tried upgrading to 1.0.2 but I have this error with trac-admin :Error: The current storage engine is MyISAM. It must be InnoDB or NDB storage engine to support transactions.

Comment: MyISAM has never been supported as a storage engine for Trac, however this wasn't enforced for Trac < 1.0.2. You'll need to convert your storage engine using the instructions [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/MySqlDb#Conversion).

Comment: Also, I highly recommend you upgrade to Trac 1.0.6post2, which is the [latest version](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDownload). What version have you been running up until now?

Comment: Trac should have no problem working with a bare git repository, but you are correct that in the case of a bare repository you won't be pointing to a `.git` subdirectory. I wonder if you have a permissions issue instead.

Comment: I have already done that but still got the error with trac admin when adding a repository on cli.

Comment: I'm unsure of which comment you are replying to. Are you on Trac 1.0.6 now? What are the permissions on your git repository?

Comment: I think there is no issue with permissions. The repository are group writable and readable by Apache. In fact when adding those repository on a trac instance I am using root.

Comment: I have already tried the latest.  Based on my testing the error is encountered from version 1.0.2 and up.

Comment: Could you please try creating and adding a new git bare repository? If that works, we can isolate the issue to your particular repository.

Comment: The error is raised [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.6/tracopt/versioncontrol/git/PyGIT.py?marks=371-384#L37). The only possibilities I see are that the control files are missing or the path is invalid. Now that I look more closely I don't think it could be a permissions issue. We've had issues in the past with users having ZWSP unicode characters in the path due to cutting and pasting the path from a web page that rendered the file paths with ZWSPs between each path separator. Which platform are you on and which version of Git?

Comment: Sorry, the previous link was truncated. The error is raised [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.6/tracopt/versioncontrol/git/PyGIT.py?marks=371-384#L370).

Comment: I am using linux (rhel6) with git version 2.3.0.

Comment: Let me know when you've had a chance to create and add a new repository. I take back what I said earlier about the impossibility of a permissions issue, I think that the error you are seeing could be caused by a permissions issue. I think this issue couldn't be too complex, we are just overlooking something obvious.